# Calling data from api and not display on fronted table but Its on the console in angular

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, typescript, api

Data fetched from API is not getting displayed on the screen but I am getting the data in the console.

Here is the .ts file.

```js
export class VisibilityComponent implements OnInit {
  

  check = false;
  pmDetails1: IEmployee[];
  constructor( private userService: UserService) {
    this.pmDetails1 = [];
     }

  ngOnInit() {
  
     this.userService.getAllEmployee().subscribe((pmDetails1:       IEmployee[]) => {
      this.pmDetails1 = pmDetails1;
      console.log(this.pmDetails1);
    });


   }
   onItemChange(value) {
    if (value === '1' ) {
      this.check = true;
    } else {
      this.check = false;
    }
 }
 }
```

here is the HTML file

```html
<div>
          <table class="table table-light" style="border: 1px solid">
            <thead style="background-color: aqua">
              <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr
                *ngFor="let p of pmDetails1"
              >
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="{{ p.id }}"
                    [checked]="check"
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{{p.name}}</td>
                <td>{{p.role}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

And here is the output on the console

[image]

Please help me to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data doesn't contain the elements `id`, `name` and `role`.

Instead it has `employeeId`, `employeeName` and `employeeRole`. You need to update your table code.

```
<td>
    <input
       type="checkbox"
       value="{{ p.employeeId }}"
       [checked]="check"
    />
</td>
<td>{{p.employeeName}}</td>
<td>{{p.employeeRole}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.